# Running Website Natively On Phone Apps

Tags: android, iphone, web

I have customers wanting my website in app form, but the website is responsive. I've been looking for an open source project or code to just run the website in an app or open up their default browser to direct them to it. They just want the button.

1. Is there an open source project to make it easy to develop that code for iOS, Android, etc.
2. Are there any issues with running a website natively? Aka, same as cross-browser issues or..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Apache-Cordova at [this](http://cordova.apache.org/) link. It is multi-platform and free/opensource.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can use WebView.

> Android WebView is a system component powered by Chrome that allows Android apps to **display** web content.

For more information about Android WebView, please visit the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)